# ¿Por qué un consulta con una función SUM me rertona NULL en vez de 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL Server :

```
select 
 case 
   when rut_trabajador = '13122585-7' then sum(distinct VALOR_PRESTAMO)+35000 
   when rut_trabajador = '13079182-4' then sum(distinct VALOR_PRESTAMO)+35000    
   -- when some unrelated condition...
   else 0 
 end as PRESTAMOS
from Prestamos where RUT_TRABAJADOR='16913361-1' AND FECHA_PRESTAMO 
BETWEEN '30-03-2017' AND '13-04-2017'
group by RUT_TRABAJADOR
```

Se supone que esta consulta debe devolver el valor de `0` pero al ejecutarlo no me muestra nada. ¿Cómo puedo modificarla para que me devuelva el valor de `0`?

Comment: Si no te muestra datos y a su vez no te muestra errores de codigo es por que la ejecución de dicho query no retorna datos, es decir ningun dato cumple con las condiciones de la consulta que estas utilizando. Verifica las condiciones que necesitas y si son las mismas de la consulta.

Comment: efectivamente, el problema surge cuando agrego el GROUP BY RUT_TRABAJADOR, ya que al no agregar esto, me retorna el valor 0

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente, el problema es el siguiente: una suma sobre un conjunto de filas funcionará de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT SUM(T.VALOR)
       FROM ( SELECT 1 AS VALOR) T;
```

El retorno obviamente será 1, pero si forzamos la condición para que la consulta no retorne filas a sumar:

```
SELECT SUM(T.VALOR)
       FROM (SELECT 1 AS VALOR) T
       WHERE T.VALOR <> 1;
```

El resultado final será `NULL`, para solucionarlo, podemos usar  `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(T.VALOR),0)
       FROM (SELECT 1 AS VALOR) T
       WHERE T.VALOR <> 1;
```

En tu ejemplo, lo resolverías de la misma forma:

```
select COALESCE(
 case 
   when rut_trabajador = '13122585-7' then sum(distinct VALOR_PRESTAMO)+35000 
   when rut_trabajador = '13079182-4' then sum(distinct VALOR_PRESTAMO)+35000    
   -- when some unrelated condition...
   else 0 
 end, 0) as PRESTAMOS
from Prestamos where RUT_TRABAJADOR='16913361-1' AND FECHA_PRESTAMO 
BETWEEN '30-03-2017' AND '13-04-2017'
group by RUT_TRABAJADOR
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido esta respuesta